# React Material UI Collapse

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I need a Collapse example. please show me a simple material-UI Collapse.

```
 <Button color="primary" startIcon={<LocalGroceryStoreOutlined />}> Credit charge</Button>
      
                <Collapse >test</Collapse>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const { useState } = React;
const {
    Button,
    Collapse,
    colors,
    CssBaseline,
    ThemeProvider,
    Typography,
    Container,
    createTheme,
    Box,
    SvgIcon,
    Link,
} = MaterialUI;
const Credit = (props) => {
    const {id} = props;
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    return (
        <div className="my-4">
            <div>
                <Button color="primary"
                        onClick={() => setOpen(state => !open)}> click me</Button>

            </div>

            <div>
                <Collapse in={open}>test</Collapse>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
ReactDOM.render(<Credit />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>


  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@mui/material@latest/umd/material-ui.development.js" crossOrigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@latest/babel.min.js" crossOrigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />
</body>
```